# Is it possible to add HDD with existing content to Synology DiskStation without loosing data?

Tags: hard-drive, nas, synology

I have an existing HDD (ext4) that already has some data and a Synology DiskStation device (DS218play), which has no disks at the moment.

I would like to add this HDD to the NAS device, but need for the existing data to be preserved. Is it achievable without copying the data to another HDD and then to NAS?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I have no experience in synology and I don't know what is possible or not. But if the disk has enough disk space, let's say half of it and I had to do that on a linux NAS, I would reduce the size of the ext4 partition, create the NAS partition on the rest, transfer my data to my new partition, delete the old one, and grow the new partition to occupy the full disk.

Now, as Richard said in comment, if you do not make a backup first, whatever you do will be risky.

Comment: This might work ... but there is a *massive* risk that something goes wrong and the NAS blows away your existing partition and you'll lose everything. If you value your data then I'd be nervous about doing this.

Comment: that's true, but in all case, it would be better to make a backup, which he seems to lacks the ressource to make.